# Accessing Iframe inside Iframe

Tags: iframe, protractor, jasmine-node

I am working on Angular app, which runs inside non-angular page. On my angular page, i have iframe(iframe2) inside another iframe(iframe1). I am able to move to iframe1 from non angular page, but i am not able to access iframe2 from iframe1  it throws error "angular could not be found on the window"

```
it('Iframes Testing',function(){

brower.driver.navigate().to('url')
browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("username");
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("password");
browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click();
 browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        element(by.model('formname')).click();  

});
```

Comment: I am able to perform all the operations on iframe1, but not sure why i am not able to access iframe2 which is inside iframe1.

Comment: it would be great help if you can share some more code or jsfiddle so as to make it easy to understand what you are expecting ...

Comment: @Suk were you able to solve nested iframe ??? I am having the same now. please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: @Nick yes i was able to resolve the issue. Below is the piece of code i used   
 browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
            browser.waitForAngular();
browser.driver.switchTo().frame(browser.driver.findElement(by.css()));